# Why doesn't the Weinberg-Witten theorem forbid collinear photons?

Tags: photons, quantum-gravity, matrix-elements

The [Weinberg-Witten theorem](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(80)90212-9) tells us that any theory that has an effective graviton, i.e. a massless helicity-2 particle as a state in the free-particle Fock space, cannot have a gauge-invariant and Lorentz-covariant stress-energy tensor that gives the graviton nonzero energy. This is intended as a no-go theorem ruling out composite gravitons, because if the theory can be expressed using only particles of spin $\le 1$ then it presumably will have such a tensor.

A composite graviton would be a bound state of lower-spin particles such as gauge bosons, with that sum of their spins in the direction of propagation equal to 2. My question is: why does the state need to be bound? Why are we only interested in states that can be called "particles"? QED, for instance, includes massless states of helicity 2: states with 2 photons that just happen to have the same  direction and spin. They are not single particles, but they are part of the Hilbert space, and matrix elements exist for them. The argument of Weinberg-Witten would seem to apply. Yet QED does have a covariant stress-energy tensor, and collinear two-photon states do have nonzero energy. Why isn't this forbidden?

I think I have a partial answer: the proof of the WW theorem derives a contradiction by writing down the tensor (at the origin) as an operator on the gauge-fixed Fock space, taking its matrix elements between single-graviton states of different momenta, and taking a limit as the momenta approach coincidence while we shift the Lorentz frame to make the momenta equal and opposite. Thus it's not enough for the graviton to have nonzero expected energy; it must have nonzero matrix elements even between states of unequal momenta. Since we are talking about an operator at a point, this seems like a reasonable assumption. Yet it seems to me that this is where my "collinear photon" case falls out: We can (I think) write the electromagnetic stress energy tensor as a sum of term of the form $a^\dagger_k a_{k'}$, meaning that we only get a nonzero matrix element when at most one photon has different momenta between the two states. Since we want states with different directions for the momenta of the collinear particle pairs, we get zero and cannot derive a contradiction.

Is this correct? Or am I perhaps confusing myself by thinking about pure momentum states rather than normalizable wavepackets? This was done in the original proof, but perhaps it introduces problems with more than one particle?

Of course, the really important question is: what changes when the state is bound; i.e. an actual composite graviton? Is it possible that we have a new loophole for the WW theorem, where we can have composite gravitons as long as we somehow force the stress-energy tensor to de diagonal in the momentum?

Comment: A photon is uncharged (under $U(1)$) so it doesn't source its spin-1 current. This is consistent with WW theorem. On the other hand, a gluon is charged (under color transformations) and it does source its corresponding spin-1 current. WW theorem then tells us that its current is then not Lorentz covariant which is true (the current is not gauge-invariant). Similarly, the graviton is charged (under diffeos) and its current (stress tensor) is not Lorentz covariant (the stress tensor is not gauge (diffeo)-invariant.).

Comment: @Prahar Yes, all of that is correct. But you don't seem to be addressing my question, so what are you trying to say?

Comment: Apologies, I think I misread a comment you made in your post and I was trying to correct it. Anyway, QED may have a Lorentz covariant stress tensor but that stress tensor is NOT gauge invariant under diffeos. It is of course gauge-invariant under $U(1)$ symmetry, but once you have a massless spin-2 particle (bound or not) you immediately have diffeomorphisms as a gauge symmetry and all gauge-invariant operators must be invariant under (small) diffeomorphisms. The stress-tensor is not invariant under diffeomorphisms.

Comment: @Qmechanic, would you mind explaining why you added the tag "photons"? I would have thought that's much too broad a topic for this question. Am I missing something about the tag system?

Comment: Hi @Ahron Maline. Welcome to Phys.SE. Yeah, it is not ideal. Feel free to improve the tags.

Comment: @Prahar In fact the electromagnetic part of the stress energy tensor is covariant under diffeomorphisms.  After all, the tensor appears in the Einstein Field Equation! Only the gravitational contribution is noncovariant.

Anyhow, my question doesn't really require diffeo covariance at all. We can talk about pure QED on Minkowski spacetime, and the question remains: why doesn't the argument of WW forbid collinear photon states?

Comment: covariant does not mean INvariant. Operators have to gauge INvariant, not covariant.

Comment: @Prahar What do you mean? Why would we want something like a tensor operator to be invariant, when it isn't even a Lorentz scalar?

Comment: Lorentz symmetry is a global symmetry so operators can transform non-trivially under that. (Small) Diffeomorphisms are a _gauge_ symmetry and operators must be invariant under gauge symmetries. The point of WW is that the moment you have a massless spin-2 particle you also have diffeomorphisms as a gauge symmetry and consequently, all physical operators on the Hilbert space must be invariant under this gauge symmetry.

Comment: Similarly, whenever you have a massless spin-1 particle, you immediately have $U(1)$ as a gauge symmetry (or more generally, any compact Lie group $G$) and then all physical operators must be invariant under this gauge symmetry. Operators can transform under the global $U(1)$ (which is a physical symmetry) but must be invariant under a local $U(1)$ (which is a gauge symmetry).

Comment: @Prahar OK, you are right that the EM part of the tensor, as it appears in the EFE, is not gauge-invariant; it depends on the metric. What I should have said is that using the split $g = \eta + h$, we can look at just the free-photon energy (the $\eta$ term) and omit the photon-graviton interaction. That will give us a gauge-invariant tensor, so WW should apply.



Alternatively, we don't have to allow diffeos at all. My question is about pairs of photons, in ordinary QED on Minkowski. Why can't we apply WW's argument and get a contradiction?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135670/discussion-between-prahar-and-ahron-maline).

Comment: @Prahar, I'd like to continue our discussion, but the chatroom has been closed due to inactivity. Can it be reopened? Or would you like to start a new one?

Comment: Guess I'll just continue here. Prahar, you argued that as soon as we have gravity in the theory, the WW theorem becomes trivially satisfied, because the currents and the stress-energy tensor are not diffeomorphism invariant just because they are local operators. I do not think this is correct.

Comment: If we are told that the stress-energy tensor T of the standard model is gauge-and Lorentz covariant, we can correctly use WW to conclude that all massless particles in the SM (that contribute to T) are of spin 1 or less. This implication remains valid even when we add gravity to the theory. Conversely, in unbroken supergravity, where the gravitino is a massless particle of spin 3/2, WW tells us that T cannot be invariant under the spin 3/2 gauge freedom, the generator of the SUSY current. The fact that T moves under diffeos is not sufficient.

Comment: The reason is that the proof of WW does not actually use gauge or diffeo invariance, only Lorentz covariance of T.  The issue of gauge/diffeo invariance only plays an indirect role: WW are working in a formalism where gauge-non-invariant operators are made well-defined by choosing a physical gauge, such as Coulomb or axial gauge. Then since the gauge condition is not Lorentz invariant, those operators lose Lorentz covariance as well - a Lorentz transformation must be followed by a gauge transformation to return to the chosen gauge.

Comment: For gravity this means that operators that depend on the dynamic metric lose Lorentz covariance. But a stress-energy tensor defined using the background Minkowski metric is an operator on the space of "free" matter particles propagating on that background; it does not "know" about the diffeo invariance and is a well defined operator without any gauge-fixing condition. Therefore is is Lorentz covariant and WW applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I am satisfied that the "partial answer" I included in the question is the correct answer. The proof of the WW theorem involves matrix elements of the form $$\langle p|T^{\mu\nu}(x)|p'\rangle, $$ where $|p\rangle$ is a momentum eigenstate of the spin-2 particle and $p,p'$ are two nearly equal null momenta. The proof relies on this matrix element being nonzero, while it does equal zero for my case of two collinear photons. The operator $T^{\mu\nu}$ cannot change the momenta of two different photons, because it is only quadratic in the photon field $A^\mu$. Therefore the proof does not apply, and such states can of course exist.

The reason I was dissatisfied with the answer, and called it only "partial", was that I didn't understand why we should be so confident that the above matrix element does not vanish when $|p\rangle$ is a single-particle state such as an "emergent graviton" that is a bound state of other fields. If it can vanish when the underlying particles are not bound, then how do we know that creating a bound state will change things?

Now I think I get it: the condition $\langle p|T^{\mu\nu}(x)|p'\rangle\ne0 $ is basically an intuitive physical requirement. It means that if (hypothetically) there was a an interaction of the form $T^{\mu\nu}h_{\mu\nu}$ (and of course there is such an interaction, namely gravity, but we do not require this), then a  background field $h_{\mu\nu}$  with a small gradient could cause slight changes in the momentum of our particle, making it move along a curved trajectory. This can be taken as a reasonable definition of what is meant by the particle being "charged under $T^{\mu\nu}$", and this is what is required for the WW theorem to apply.

This behavior is also pretty close to what we mean by a state being "bound", namely that the different components maintain a shared trajectory when "pushed around" by mild forces. But it does not describe particles that just happen to be collinear; in that case the force will tend to spread the trajectories slightly apart.